# Cross-compiling SDL 2.0 application between supported platforms

Tags: sdl, cross-compiling

I'm looking for a "Hello World" SDL 2.0 project that cross-compiles between all supported platforms: Windows, Linux, Mac, Android and iOS. Is there anything like that? I could not find on the official forums or docs.

What tools are recommended? CMake or SCons? Can it be done with just "make"?

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if that's exactly what you're looking for, but I've just made a <s>small tutorial on how to cross-compile SDL2 projects from Linux to Windows.</s> **Dead Link**

Basically, install [*MinGW*](http://www.mingw.org/) and set your compilation flags to the following (`Makefile` example):

```
# Where your MinGW SDL is installed
SDL_ROOT_DIR = /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32

CFLAGS   = `$(SDL_ROOT_DIR)/bin/sdl2-config --cflags`
           -Wall -Wextra
CXXFLAGS = `$(SDL_ROOT_DIR)/bin/sdl2-config --cflags`
           -Wall -Wextra
LDFLAGS  = `$(SDL_ROOT_DIR)/bin/sdl2-config --libs` \
           -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_gfx \
           -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

In-depth explanations [here](http://osdl.sourceforge.net/main/documentation/rendering/SDL-cross-compilation.html) and [here](http://icculus.org/~dolson/sdl/).

Answer (score 2):

If you download the source for SDL2, there are a number of short example programs that compile on all supported platforms in the "test" directory.